# Convert a LambdaExpression to typed Expression<Func<T, object>> with boxing return values

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, boxing, linq-expressions

I want to build the following Expression:

```
Expression<Func<T, object>>
```

I have currently the following code:

```
public class Strategy<T>
{
    private static Expression<Func<T, object>> GetIt(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
    {
        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        MemberExpression property = Expression.Property(parameter, propertyInfo);
        Type funcType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T), typeof(object));

        //next line fails: can't convert int to object
        LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(funcType, property, parameter);

        Expression<Func<T, object>> retval = (Expression<Func<T, object>>)lambda;
        return retval;
    }
}
```

My PropertyInfo object has a returntype of "int".
How can i use boxing in my Expression?

Comment: `Expression<Func<T, object>> retval = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(Expression.Convert(property, typeof(object)), parameter);`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ExpressionGetter<T>
    {
        public static Expression<Func<T, Object>> Get(PropertyInfo pInfo)
        {
            ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
            MemberExpression property = Expression.Property(parameter, pInfo);
            Type funcType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(T), typeof(object));

            //next line fails: can't convert int to object

            LambdaExpression lambda;
            if (typeof (T).IsClass == false && typeof (T).IsInterface == false)
                lambda = Expression.Lambda(funcType, Expression.Convert(property, typeof (Object)), parameter);
            else
                lambda = Expression.Lambda(funcType, property, parameter);

            return (Expression<Func<T, object>>)lambda;
        }
    }
```